# Em análise na parte de "Votos para Reabrir" há uma frase parcialmente traduzida

Tags: bug, tradução

Na parte de [análise na parte de "Votos para Reabrir"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/92416), encontrei ali um frase parcialmente traduzida:

> Esta pergunta deve ser reaberta?
>
> **It was initially closed as** principalmente baseada em opiniões

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É um erro ou não deu tempo traduzir ainda?

Comment: Você mesmo pode traduzi-la, basta verificar se essa string está no transifex. Links úteis: [Mil tradutores são melhores que um](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2705/4808) / [Como ajudar quem traduz o site?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4764/4808)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu já sugeri essa alteração no [transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt). Agora é só esperar pela revisão.